# How to setup MinGW on Linux for using pdcurses?

Tags: linux, mingw, cross-compiling, wine, pdcurses

I installed WINE (for testing and debugging the binaries without the need for Windows) and MinGW on a Linux for cross-compiling purposes, but when I try to compile anything that requires curses, MinGW complains that it cannot find the header file "curses.h". So, I believe a good solution would be to install pdcurses, but how come? And after installed, how to link it to a program being compiled? I mean: for some reason, MinGW can't find pdcurses.

Comment: I don't get the WINE part. MinGW exists on Linux as a proper cross-compiler. Anyway, I suppose you should just cross-compile pdcurses or ncurses.

Comment: I installed WINE so I don’t need a Windows to test or debug the binaries. Everything is kept in Linux.

Comment: This night I succeeded installing pdcurses system wide, but, somehow, MinGW still cannot see "curses.h" or link it, in case you just copy it to the current directory. There must have something to do on how it configures its paths, and I don’t have a clue on how to fix it.

Comment: There's no point in cross-compiling pdcurses as the source already comes with different folders for each architecture, including x11. The only issue is, for some reason, after a "make install", MinGW doesn't find it.